# ¿Cómo agregar una aplicación de consola personalizada en el Programador de tareas?

Tags: c#, windows, consola

**Trasfondo:**

He desarrollado una aplicación de consola en C# cuya funcionalidad consiste en leer información de un archivo XML para después consultar información de una base de datos en Access y exportar los resultados de la consulta en una archivo Excel (.xslx).

En el código fuente de la aplicación de consola, he establecido la ruta del archivo de configuración de esta manera:

```
const string RutaArcXML = @".\ArchivoConfiguracion.xml";
```

Se debe crear una tarea personalizada para ejecutar esta funcionalidad cada día *(en un horario específico)*.

**Problema:**

Debido a que la aplicación de consola requiere consultar un archivo XML *(que contiene la información requerida para generar consultar en la base de datos de Access)* y tanto la aplicación de consola como el archivo XML **deben estar en la misma ubicación/carpeta**, cuando creo la tarea programada usando la funcionalidad nativa de Windows llamada [Programador de tareas](http://windows.microsoft.com/es-co/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7), ésta solo me permite agregar la aplicación de consola.

Al ejecutar la tarea programada me aparece el siguiente error:

> Error: no se pudo encontrar el archivo 'C:\Windows\System32\ArchivoConfiguracion.xml'

La aplicación de consola queda almacenada en la ruta:

> C:\Windows\System32\

He intentado manualmente colocar el archivo XML en la misma ubicación mencionada en líneas anteriores, pero al ejecutar nuevamente la tarea programada, sigue sin encontrar el archivo de configuración.

Mi pregunta es:

**¿Cómo agregar una aplicación de consola personalizada en el Programador de tareas?**<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Otras opciones que he consultado es aplicar código personalizado que usa la clase [TaskScheduler](https://escarbandocodigo.wordpress.com/2009/10/21/crear-tareas-programadas-desde-c/), pero este acercamiento obtiene los mismos resultados que he descrito en esta pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dado que la aplicación va a buscar el archivo xml en la carpeta de ejecución de la aplicación debes indicarle a la tarea que se inicie en esta carpeta.

Al programar la tarea en Windows tienes una opción "Iniciar en":

[image: Opción Iniciar en]

en esta opción deberías indicar la carpeta en la que se debería ejecutar la aplicación.

En cualquier caso nos es buena opción la de meter rutas de los archivos de datos como constantes en tu aplicación. Por lo general resulta más práctico introducir una clave en el archivo de configuración de la aplicación de forma que en un momento dado puedas modificarla sin necesidad de recompilar y reinstalar la aplicación.

Comment: Gracias, acabo de hacer la prueba y funciona correctamente. Es posible que genere una nueva pregunta para establecer una mejor manera de referencias los recursos que use la aplicación de consola; En este punto ¿se refiere a usar un archivo de recursos .resx para almacenar las rutas de los archivos?

Comment: No, me refiero a crear una entrada en la sección AppSettings del App.config. Los archivos de recursos se compilan con la aplicación con lo que tendrías el mismo problema a la hora de modificarlos. El archivo de configuración, en cambio, es un archivo de texto que puedes editar en cualquier momento.

Comment: comprendo, pero en mi caso, la aplicación consume datos de una base de datos de un programa tercero y la configuración del programa "que he desarrollado" consiste también en un archivo XML que contiene un DataTable. Este archivo además debe ser modificado a través de una interfaz que hace parte de este desarrollo.

Comment: Pero eso es independiente. La cadena de conexión a la base de datos podrías incluirla también en el archivo de configuración. De esta forma podrías modificarla si quisieras alternar entre una base de datos de pruebas y la de producción por ejemplo. En cuanto al XML, si tienes una entrada en la que configuras la carpeta de ficheros de datos, no tendrías más que almacenar todos los XMLs que necesites en esa carpeta y acceder a ellos para leer, modificar o lo que necesites.

Comment: Me temo que no es tan sencillo; la cadena de la base de datos es de un software ajeno a la empresa; la cadena de conexión se encuentra en el registro del equipo que cuente con el software tercero instalado. Agradezco sus contribuciones a esta pregunta y al sitio de Stack Overflow en Español. Saludos.